# json parsing with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, urllib

I try to parse this little json, i want to take the number :

> {"nombre":18747}

I try :

```
import urllib.request
request = urllib.request.Request("http://myurl.com")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
print (response.read().decode('utf-8')) //print ->  {"nombre":18747}

import json
json = (response.read().decode('utf-8'))
json.loads(json)
```

But I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    json.loads('json')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *already* read the network data; you cannot read it twice. And you are rebinding `json` to the network-read data, replacing the module reference. Don't use `json` for that reference!

Remove the `print` statement, use `data` for the string reference and it'll work.

Working code:

```
import urllib.request
import json

request = urllib.request.Request("http://httpbin.org/get")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
encoding = response.info().get_content_charset('utf8')
data = json.loads(response.read().decode(encoding))
```

where we also make use of any `charset` parameter on the response to ensure we use the right codec to decode the response data.

For the `http://httpbin.org/get` url above, this produces:

```
{'args': {}, 'headers': {'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'Accept-Encoding': 'identity', 'Connection': 'close', 'User-Agent': 'Python-urllib/3.3'}, 'origin': '12.34.56.78', 'url': 'http://httpbin.org/get'}
```

Comment: Yep but i have this :   File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 352, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: Yep, now i have : ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: @Martialp: Does the exact code I posted in my answer work for you? Try that first. Then move on from there.

Comment: With the adresse in your code it's works, not with my adresse, so your solution is ok, the probleme is on my side :)

Answer (score 1):

name your string differently, for example instead :

```
json = (response.read().decode('utf-8'))
json.loads(json)
```

write :

```
input = (response.read().decode('utf-8'))
json.loads(input)
```

With the way it is currently in your question, you are overriding imported json module with that variable name which is string. Also remove the print statement.