# Python httplib retrieve json object from getresponse()

Tags: python, json, httplib

So I currently working on a POST request to an api.

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.syncano.io')
conn.request(method="POST", url=url, body=postdata, headers=headers)
resp = conn.getresponse()
```

I used `resp.read()` but it returns me a string. Are there any way for me to read the response as a JSON object where I could get the result simply by doing `resp['result']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the response body is valid JSON

```
import json

respBody = resp.read()

responseObject = json.loads(respBody)
```

Will create a python dictionary: "responseObject" from the JSON response body.

More detail: [json parsing with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525513/json-parsing-with-python)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still doesn't work. It returns an error: `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: This is the output: `{"result": 0.5872620044551499}`

Comment: Make sure you're not calling resp.read() twice. Get the result from the first call and pass it into json.loads

Comment: Opps, you are right. I did called resp.read() twice. Thanks and it is working now!